# I can't find the mistake/s in a solution to an algebra problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know what to name the title.

I've been trying to solve this problem, which i found here https://testbook.com/question-answer/if-a-b-c2frac1a-frac1b--5fac0b426b2a22453f832c33

> If $a+b+c=2$, $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=0$, $ac=\frac{4}{b}$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=28$, then what's the value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$?

These two seemingly correct solutions give two different answers, namely $8$ and $6\frac{2}{3}$. I've been trying to pinpoint the mistake/es, but so far i have failed. Can you help me out?

#### My solution

$$8=(a+b+c)^3=(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3a^2(b+c)+3b^2(a+c)+3c^2(a+b)+6abc=$$
$$=28+3(a^2(a+b+c-a)+b^2(a+b+c-b)+c^2(a+b+c-c))+6b\times ac=$$
$$=28+3(a^2(2-a)+b^2(2-b)+c^2(2-c))+6b\times \frac{4}{b}=$$
$$=28+6(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3(a^3+b^3+c^3)+24=6(a^2+b^2+c^2)+28-3\times 28+24$$
$$6(a^2+b^2+c^2)+28-3\times 28+24=8$$
$$6(a^2+b^2+c^2)=40$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=\frac{40}{6}=6\frac{2}{3}$$

#### The other solution

We can use the identity
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$
Then
$$28-3b\times ac=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-abc(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}))$$
$$28-3b\times \frac{4}{b}=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-abc\times 0)$$
$$28-12=2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=\frac{28-12}{2}=8$$

Comment: (Wolfram states that)There are no solutions to the system, so different ways of manipulating it could lead to different results.

Comment: I verified that if you only used $a+b+c = 2, abc = 4, a^3+b^3+c^3 = 28$, then we can solve for $ \{ a, b, c\}$ and that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 6+ 2/3$ as OP has shown.

Comment: Oh yeah! Now i want to prove that, if $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=0$, then there is no such solution.

Comment: Right, with those 3 equations, you can show that $ab+bc+ca = -4/3$, hence there is no solution if we also require $ab+bc+ca = 0 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is with the problem itself, as the system is  inconsistent.

OP's work is correct, and only uses $a+b+c = 2, abc = 4, a^3+b^3+c^3 = 28$.
This implies that $ab+bc+ ca = - 4/3$ (OP's work essentially shows this), which is inconsistent with $ab+bc+ca = 0 $.